# Shatter effect when closing windows in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu

I'm running kubuntu 22.04 on vmware and on the last virtual machine I had a cool shatter effect where pieces flew everywhere when closing windows or shutting down.  I had deleted that machine and couldn't find that option when I made another virtual machine.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is called "Fall Apart":  https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/linux/make-kde-desktop-stunning

Comment: I went into settings, Workspace Behavior-Desktop Effects, and there's no fall apart option, no magic lamp option, etc.

Comment: It may help if you're specific with details; Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format; so 22.0 is invalid; as 0 is not a valid month. It was likely a typo, but please correct.

Comment: In Kubuntu 22.04, if you go to the KMenu then search for Desktop Effects.  Once in Desktop Effects, scroll down into the Appearance section and it is right below Fading Popups.

Comment: But, I just barely installed the `kubuntu-desktop` in 22.04 from an existing installation of Xubuntu and all those settings were right there.  Maybe during your install you didn't select the right packages?

Comment: Many of those options, fading popups, fall apart, magic lamp, etc. were simply not along.  I reinstalled Kubuntu and now I have all those options again.